# What does MtGox order status mean?

Tags: mtgox, api

"Your Open Orders" in MtGox lists all of our orders. However, some orders are not *open*. I sometimes see them as *pending*.

The [HTTPv1 API](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#Your_open_orders) states that there are 6 possible statuses:

1. pending
2. executing
3. post-pending
4. open
5. stop
6. invalid

What do these statuses mean?

Comment: `pending` means that they received your order request, but it's still queued and not inserted yet in the order book.

Comment: @Lohoris, what does a post-pending refer to?

Comment: I've no idea, or I would have posted a proper answer ;)